# How is it possible to make multiple rectangle instances in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to create multiple rectangles using a for loop with PyGame but I'm not really clear on how I could do this. My first approach was storing all rectangle instances in an array but then I ran into another problem, how to assign a `.get_rect()` to it. So I did this:

```
def MultiRect(amount):
    objects = []
    objectsRect = []

    for i in range(0, amount):
        objects.append(pygame.Surface([200,100]).convert())
        objects[i].fill((130,130,130))
        objectsRect.append(objects[i].get_rect())
```

So what I tried to do was make two arrays, one stores the instance and the other stores the `instance.get_rect()` but I know this is the wrong way to do it and I also get multiple `out of range` errors. Is there another way I could go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You could just directly instantiate a bunch of Rects, like

```
for i in range(0,amount):
    objectsRect.append(pygame.Rect(left,top,width,height))
```

Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: If I'm using this, do I need to use the `.get_rect()` method to be able to evaluate collision? Because I was under the impression that each instance of a rectangle should have a return value from `pygame.Surface.get_rect()`.

Comment: @Toby if you only need to use Rect objects, you can test collision like rectObject.colliderect(otherRectObject). the [pygame docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.contains) are helpful with this

Answer (score 0):

So what is actually not working in your code? I don't see any problems here. It is strange however why do pass surface size in square brackets, But this will cause no errors probably, it is also acceptable. When do you have `out of range` error?